# excel: the name but not the contents of a named range is the only option shown in drop down list

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, data-validation

I have a sheet '`orders`' and a sheet '`lists`.' In lists, I have a list of valid fruits:

```
a1:  fruits
a2:  apple
a3:  orange
a4:  someone may add something here at any time
```

I have a named range '`fruits`' in the workbook (not in the sheet) with the value "`fruits!$a$2:index(fruits!$a$2:$a$100, counta(fruits!$a$2:$a$100))`." With this setup, I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to open the 'go to' box and then type in 'fruits' and hit return, then cells a2, a3, and a4 are correctly selected in tab 'lists.'

In sheet '`orders`' I have header in column b1 '`the fruit`,' and I have selected all the cells below the header in b1 and have gone to Data -> Data Validation, Allow -> List, Source -> fruits and pressed ok. Then I click on a cell below b1.

Usually, and elsewhere for similar situations in this workbook, this works and in the resulting drop down list I correctly see:

- apple
- orange
- someone may add something here at any time

However, now instead I see in the drop down list only:

- fruits

What gives? I've successfully maneuvered this process in hundreds of documents in the past. Now it isn't working - has this happened to you, too? Why does this error manifest?

NOTE: I have manual calculation ticked. Does this matter?

Answer (score 0):

This must be some kind of bug. Given the situation above, click on `orders!a2` and go to  Data -> Data Validation, Allow -> List, Source -> delete fruits and replace with `lists!$a$2:$a$4` and press OK. Click on `orders!a2` and a drop down box will appear as expected with:

- apple
- orange
- someone may add something here at any time

Now go into the same dialog box, overwrite with '`fruits`' again in the source, and press OK. Now everything works as expected. Anyone know what went wrong?